# How to hit axios request from Jest test page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to hit an axios request from my code.test.js file here:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('get-data', () => {

let data = {start_date:"2017-06-30",end_date:"2017-07-07",graph:"all"}

let sandbox;
let server;
beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    server = sandbox.useFakeServer();
});
afterEach(() => {
    server.restore();
    sandbox.restore();
});

it('should display a blankslate', (done) => {
    axios.get('/api/get/data?data='+JSON.stringify(data))
        .then((response.data) => {
        console.log(response)
            /*expect($('#users').innerHTML)
            .to.equal('The list is empty.')*/ })
        .then(done, done);
    setTimeout(() => server.respond([200,
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    '[]']), 0);
});
})
```

But I get console.log(response.data) as undefined.

Can anyone tell me how to get data here in response ?

Comment: Consider checking out [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock)

Answer (score 1):

Technically in your tests you shouldn't be actually doing a request, but rather mocking it and testing side effects.

However if I remember correctly `jest` mocks everything by default unless told not too. In your `package.json` add the following section and contents:

`{
  "jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "axios",
    ]
  }
}`

This should allow you to do your actual network request as necessary in the test. You could also pass the `"automock": true,` property into the `jest` section if you wanted to disable automocking.

**Documentation:**

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#automock-boolean

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#unmockedmodulepathpatterns-array-string

Comment: Still the `response.data` is coming undefined although the other fields in `response` are coming correctly

Comment: In the past automocking was enabled by default but right now it's disabled since v15 - see https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/09/01/jest-15.html#disabled-automocking